# Unity2D Switching Characters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I run this it works but only once. When I tap c for the second time nothing happens. I think that I should change change the function from Update to something other. If someone could help me i would be very thankful.

```
public class SwitchPlayer2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update(){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
            {
                otherPlayer.GetComponent<Movement2D>().enabled = false;
                GetComponent<Movement2D>().enabled = true;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hajiyev Elbrus!! It works thank you very very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        if (otherPlayer.GetComponent<Movement2D>().enabled == true)
        {
            otherPlayer.GetComponent<Movement2D>().enabled = false;
            GetComponent<Movement2D>().enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            otherPlayer.GetComponent<Movement2D>().enabled = true;
            GetComponent<Movement2D>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```